# Is our site for technical questions only?

Tags: discussion, topic

> [How to buy ETH in big volume?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6738/87)

Without discussing the style of the question above, I would like to point out that a user complained about this question not being of a technical nature.

> Down vote, because this is not a question about the technology. This would be like asking on stackoverflow about buying a super computer. – Victory

Is it okay to ask <del>on stackoverflow about buying supercomputers?</del> questions not about the technology but also everything else Ethereum related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Our site is for questions about Ethereum that have objective answers.**  Mostly they will be technical questions, since Ethereum is technology.  But there could certainly be other questions that could be about economics, game theory, law, etc that are about Ethereum.  Some of them may need to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis and some of them will probably be on-topic.  A key factor in the evaluation is does the question have objective answers?  If it does, it is probably helpful to have on this site.  But if the question's answers involve arguments about economics and law, it is more likely to be off-topic and belong to another site.  Especially if a question's answers depend on speculation, such as legal questions where there are no precedents and so answers are primarily opinion-based.

Ultimately, it is up to the community to decide how to deal with the case-by-case questions.  (Moderators should try to avoid using "super-vote" to close or reopen questions that have been acted on by the community, unless the question clearly fits in the guidelines.)

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit that I am on the fence about this issue. I thought about it more since I down voted that question. Even though I have more doubts now about the matter I still feel we should avoid allowing such questions. There is too much of an incentive for questions like these to focus on self interest instead of community.

I'm long on ethereum and I want this community to foster those who wish to see the technology and utility flourish. Sometimes that may involve rejecting earnest questions simply because they are indistinguishable from self interest.